# Add Ajax Support to Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I would like to add ajax to an existing spring mvc 2.5 webapps.  But i dont know where to start.

I think spring does not support ajax integration.

Does someone know how can I accomplish this?  I was thinking that my ajaxrequest should be catch by the controller interface but I dont know where to start.
I dont want to use any ajax library at this point but just plain old ajax approach

Kindly send me links or tutorials if what I am thinking is possible please

Comment: @Mark You are a new user. Welcome but if you see a useful answer, UPvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC does not provide out of the box Ajax support. However it provides suitable extension points through its template based design to enable Ajax support very easily. Still you can implement it using **jquery** library.

Comment: Hi Nirmal,

Thanks for giving time on this.  I am a very newbie here, can you point me to a link where I could read about those topics related to the extension points.

Would surely appreciate it. -- Mark

Comment: Check this http://www.jtraining.com/blogs/ajax-with-spring-mvc-and-jquery.html may be this can help you in much better way....